# CSS 3 Inner Drop Shadow

Tags: html, css

This should be simple, I want a drop shadow, but I want it on the inside of a rectangle.  I'm looking for a place on Google, but I can't find it.

[image]

Comment: You need to use `inset` property https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-shadow

Answer (score 1):

You didn't look hard enough.

```
box-shadow: inset 2px 2px 3px 3px #333333;
```

Comment: I saw it before, but couldn't find it again. Thanks! Why -1?

Comment: [Be nice.](http://stackoverflow.com/help/be-nice) Also, you used "inse**r**t" rather than "inset".

Comment: @TheHawk - Why do you assume that sour downvoted your question? 24 users have viewed your post so far.

Comment: @TheHawk weren't me :d

Comment: @JDB ma bad XD I usually let sublime do my spelling errors ;) plus I was only joking :p

Answer (score 1):

Use `inset box-shadow`.

```css
div {
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  background: white;
  box-shadow: inset 8px 9px 3px -5px #939393;
}
body {
  background: papayawhip;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes. As mentioned by @antyrat youcan use an inset box shadow.

```css
body {
  background: #bada55;
}
.shadow {
  width: 250px;
  height: 250px;
  margin: 25px auto;
  background: white;
  box-shadow: inset 3px 3px 3px grey;
}
```

```html
<div class="shadow"></div>
```

Support - [**CanIUse.com**](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-boxshadow)

Answer (score 0):

The `inset` value is what you are looking for.

See this example:

```
box-shadow: inset 0 0 5px #000;
```

Look here for further information:
[developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-shadow](http://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-shadow)